# ApacheTomcat 8 on Windows 7

Tags: tomcat

I can’t install ApacheTomcat 8 on Windows 7. I’ve followed instruction: RUNNING and I have an error: 
“The specified service does not exist as an installed service. Unable to open service ‘tomcat8’.”
Is someone who can help me?

Comment: Perhaps you can explain more about exactly what you are doing to launch Tomcat. Have you tried running the tomcat/bit/startup.bat file?

Comment: Also, StackOverflow.com is for programming questions. Your question seems to be more of an admin nature. You may receive a better response on an alternative site, such as [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites#).

Comment: I’ve followed all instructions which I found on internet. Now I know that probably it is a problem of releases compatibility: Windows-Java-Apache Tomcat.
I will try to install Apache Tomcat on my Apple and switch my work on Apple.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it is some kind of installation failure so you should try downloading the binary version of tomcat. I am using tomcat 8 and it is working perfectly in windows 7.

https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi#8.0.50

you can download it from the above link.

and it is also possible that if you have any IDE like nebeans or ecliple already started the server, it can't start again.

as you have mentioned

> Unable to open service ‘tomcat8’.”

this message comes when you try to open the tomcat8.exe file in the bin folder.
To Start tomcat you have to run the batch file startup.bat (because you are in windows).

hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

The only solution I've found on running the tomacat 8 on Windows 7 (even as of November 2014) is to replace it with tomcat 7. I couldn't figure out what was wrong, the paths, jre, jdk. Everything seemed in place and didn't work nevertheless. I went for the version 7 of tomcat, changed the environment variable with the appropriate path (in my case `C:\tomcat_7\apache-tomcat-7.0.5`7) for `CATALINE_HOME` and everything runs smooth.

To check if tomcat server runs go to the bin directory of your tomacat version and run `"startup.bat"` from the command line.

That's it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: You're righ lennon310 this does not answer the question, it just gives the solution to the problem of not being able to run the latest version of tomcat on your computer. Thx anyway.